# PDFA is not allow with password?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I had used ghostscript for generate PDF/A with password, somehow it not working as expect.

I can have PDF with encrypted however no PDF/A compatibilities.

In other case i can create PDF/A file without password and what i got from PDF file is compatible with PDFA.

Not sure is this the case that PDF/A and password is not allow?
Any one can explain this for me?

Here my sample:

```
gs     -dPDFA=3     -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB     -dBATCH     -dNOPAUSE     -dEmbedAllFonts=true     -dSubsetFonts=true     -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK     -sDEVICE=pdfwrite     -sOwnerPassword=12345     -sUserPassword=1234     -sOutputFile=test-pass.pdf pdf.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the PDF/A-3 specification:

> The keyword **Encrypt** shall not be present in the trailer dictionary.
>
> NOTE 2 The explicit prohibition of the **Encrypt** keyword has the implicit effect of disallowing encryption and password-protected access permissions.

*(ISO 19005-3, section 6.1.3 - File trailer)*

(Similarly in ISO 19005-1 and ISO 19005-2, and surely also in ISO 19005-4.)

In other words, ***password protection is forbidden in PDF/A documents***.

This is not really surprising; PDF/A is about making sure the content is and will remain accessible for a long time. Passwords counteract this purpose...